# Https support for <int-http:outbound-gateway>

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to implement https support for `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`.

Following is the scenario:

There is `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` which accepts inbound url to Spring integration. The reply-channel of `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` and `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` are same. Based on the HeaderValueRouter, the inbound request is forwarded from request-channel of `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` to request channel of `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` . Now response is received from the outbound url and put in the reply-channel.
The url-expression of `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` is built from the MesssageHeader "http_requestUrl" attribute.

Now if I host the external app in https. What configuration I need to make in `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` to get the response in reply-channel

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is nothing to do with Spring Integration for SSL. It is a responsibility of the underlying HTTP engine. And, to be honest, it even doesn't depend on the `ClientHttpRequestFactory` implementation for the `RestTemplate`.

You just need to have the server SSL certificate and place it to the `trustStore`. That's is if your target service requires only trusting - single-way SSL.

If you need `mutual SSL`, you need to generate the key and store it in the `keyStore` for your Java and share with the server the public part - certificate.

More info you can find in the Java SSL documentation.